# Editing a UITextView with a button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a UITextView which I only want to be editable if a certain user of the app is logged in (I'm using parse.com).

My idea was to have a 'edit' button above a UITextView, that, when pressed would check to see if the right user is logged in. If the user is the correct user then it would allow edit of the UITextView, if not then I would just pop up a UIAlert.

I'm really not sure how to do this, can someone please point me in the right direction?

Here is what I have so far:

```
- (IBAction)announceEditButton:(id)sender {

    PFQuery *triClubQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Clubs"];
    [triClubQuery whereKey:@"ClubName" equalTo:_club.clubName];
    PFObject *foundClub = [triClubQuery getFirstObject];
    NSString *clubOwner = [foundClub objectForKey:@"Creator"];

   if ([clubOwner isEqualToString:[PFUser currentUser].username]){
        // do something here to edit UITextView
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have a button at all? Change the `editable` property of the text view automatically based on the logged in user.

Comment: @maddy How would I then tell the user that they don't have the authority?

Comment: That's up to you. Simply showing the text in a label instead of text view would be one way without needing any sort of alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would set `yourTextView.editable = NO;` wherever you define it (e.g. `viewDidLoad` method) and then you need to just:

```
yourTextView.editable = YES;
```

and then

```
[yourTextView becomeFirstresponder];
```

Comment: `isEditable` is the getter. Call `yourTextView.editable = YES;` to set it.

Comment: @rmaddy whoops, sorry. Corrected.